# Javascript break then back on to print html?

Tags: javascript, php

In php, if I'm echoing html I would usually break PHP then turn it back on again. Even if I had one variable in the middle e.g.

```
echo " ?>

<div class="className">Hello World</div>
<div class="className">it's a <?=$kindOfDay?></div>
<div class="className">day today</div>

<? "; ?>
```

Is there a way to do something similar in javascript? To allow me an easier way to write e.g.

```
html += '<div class="className">Hello World</div>';
html += '<div class="className">it\'s a ' + kindOfDay + '</div>';
html += '<div class="className">day today</div>';
```

Comment: This should work with Entities.  Is it not working?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: try my example below.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the three elements into a single string, but there is not really any easier way to write it.

#### Edit:

To use a multi-line string in javascript, you can do 
    html += 
    "This \
    is \
    a \
    sentence.";

Keep in mind that some browsers will insert newlines, and some wont.

Comment: This is an example, the code I'm doing actually has about 50 lines and multiple variables throughout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
html = '<div class="className">Hello World</div>' + 
        '<div class="className">it\'s a great</div>' +
        '<div class="className">day today</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are the best for this, Try:

```
var kindOfDay = 'great', 
    html = ['<div class="className">Hello World</div>',
            '<div class="className">it\'s a '+ kindOfDay + ' great</div>',
            '<div class="className">day today</div>'].join('');
```

Comment: Thanks but still very messy compared to vanilla html - I'm guessing there is no way to do it

Comment: I mean it depends. You could also use a template. But what is it that you are looking for? There are more ways...